# After deploying Qt app with macdeployqt (Qt 4.7.3) the app is broken

Tags: qt, macos, deployment

Until now deploying my Application with `macdeployqt` worked fine, but after upgrading to Qt 4.7.3 (Mac Qt SDK 1.1 Release Candidate) my program is broken after the deployment. This are the issues:

- all icons and resource images are gone (do not show up in the toolbar)
- windows don't open anymore
- Cmd+Q does not quit the app

What buzzes me is that i don't understand what causes all these problems, since `macdeployqt` simply copies the frameworks (QtGui, QtCore, QtSql, QtNetwork in my case) into the app bundle and rewrites the links of the binary and the deployed frameworks by using `otool` and `install_name_tool`. All icons and images are compiled into the binary, so the only thing i can think of is that rewriting the links (stored as strings?) overwrites data in the data section of the binary and/or code section.

What can I do to make `macdeployqt` work again?

**EDIT**: This problem also appears in a very simple test app with just one tool button that contains an icon. After `macdeployqt` this icon is not visible anymore.

**EDIT**: If would be helpful to know if anyone can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macdeployqt-version that comes shipped with QtSDK seems to be broken.

Remove QtSDK and install the libraries from the framework-only version (http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/qt-for-open-source-cpp-development-on-mac-os-x). The macdeployqt included there should work.

A bug regarding this problem is already filed for that in the Qt-Bugtracker -> http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17959